# Sound chips in 1977

Tags: history, chip, sound

By the early eighties, there were a variety of off-the-shelf sound chips suitable for use in home computers and arcade games.

What about 1977? That seems to have been just a little early; I'm not seeing any good off-the-shelf sound chips in that year. Are there any that I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sound generation might be easier using an IC, but unless you have a need for your product to be small, there's no reason you couldn't do it with a few discrete components and some general-purpose ICs.
 [This article](http://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/bipolar_transistor_cookbook_part_5) gives a few sample circuits that are useful for producing sounds, but note that for a computer there's another possibility that isn't considered here: you presumably already have a crystal oscillator to drive your clock signal, in the range of ~1-4MHz depending on the CPU you've chosen.  Feeding that into a divider circuit (which is to say a counter and a digital comparator used to toggle a flip flop) and you can produce virtually any frequency output you like.  Then to make sound, all you need to do is load the divider value into a latch that's connected to the processor bus, and use another bit to turn the sound on or off, and there you have frequency-controlled sound.  It's not as good as the multi-channel sound chips you got later, but it's better than the Sinclair Spectrum had, and that managed OK even 5 years later...

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure about 1977. The first chips that come up to me are the **TI TMS9919 aka SN76489** and **General Instruments AY-3-8910**. The AY-3-8910 was around for sure in 1978. Both were also used in a lot of arcade machines and consoles/home computers. And both have follow-up designs that are available even today.

The direct predecessor of the TMS9919 was the **SN76477**, called the *Complex Sound Generator* (the TMS9919 was called the *Digital* Complex Sound Generator). Each function could be controlled via direct inputs, so clearly a sound chip. But for use with digital systems, some glue logic (latches) would be needed. It got an article in Popular Electronics in 1978 but I don't know how long it was before it was available.

On the GI side, there were the **AY-1-0212** and **AY-3-214** before the AY-3-8910. But it's hard to qualify them already as sound chips, as they weren't really self-sufficient from today's view.

---

While the **Signetics 2637** isn't 'just' a sound chip, it offered in 1977 a single sound chanel plus white noise and loudness controll. The 2637 could be best described as a single chip video console, as it includes a video circuitry with colour abilitiy and sprites, 13x16 text, character ROM plus definable characters plus ADC for up to 4 analoge paddles or two analogue joysticks - plus said sound generator.

Answer (score 2):

Why specifically 1977?

A year later, but still in the seventies: [General Instrument AY-3-8910](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Instrument_AY-3-8910), aka Yamaha YM2149F.

Comment: I'm writing a time travel/alternate history story where the protagonists are designing a home computer in 1977. Don't want to fudge what happened when, because part of the fun of writing this kind of story is researching authentic details. So it looks like they'll have to design their own sound chip. That's okay, adds an interesting complication. They'll probably go for something as simple as possible, maybe like what the Vic-20 had.

Comment: @rwallace The VIC-20 was already a way complex machine. Keep in mind, it wasn't released until 4 years later. At the same time it was extrem restricted as it was ment to be a cheap home computer. an entusiast/self build system would be more along the lines of early modular syst like SS50 or S100 or alike. Also, there are many ways to produce integrated sound. For example if the system would be based arround a 6502 system, Timer 1 of a 6522 could be used to generate a base frequency which modified withing a full octave via an AY-1-0212 (controlled by other port bits) making a great synthesizer.

Comment: @rwallace Not sure what your setting is, but a belivable system for a hobbyist could be a KIM-1, as it was cheap, but gaot some advanced fatures, like easy expansion to 4KiB and a build in current loop to connect a TTY or terminal. With it's 6530 it would be possible to have two sound chanels using the AY-1-0212, without much effort. There was also a bus board and many third party extensions available.  Another great base would have been an OSI Model 400.

Comment: Or anything with a parallel port: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covox_Speech_Thing

Comment: @traal Erm, that's from 1986 ... 9 years too late :))

Comment: @Raffzahn It's nothing more than a bunch of resistors, nothing you couldn't do with a Centronics connector in 1970: https://hackaday.com/2014/09/29/the-lpt-dac/

Comment: @traal Indeed, it is a little surprising that Covox wasn't invented as soon as personal (or not so personal) computers became equipped with a general purpose parallel port.

Comment: @Leo I suppose PCM audio data wasn't a good use of limited system memory back then. Although Ghostbusters for C64 had small digital audio samples.

Comment: @traal Should have been plenty for synthesized waveforms, similar to what a sound chip does.

Comment: @traal For one, the question was about a *sound chip* and in my opinion that requires *some* level of independant operation. And second, a simple resistor array DAC would require most of the CPU time on a 1977 8 Bit machine. Not to mention rather large quantities (maybe even more than a KiB) of memory for generator lookup tables. Samples would be complete out of scope with 1977s Memory.

Comment: @Raffzahn One technique used in the '80s was to stop all on-screen movement before bit-banging the DAC as in this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1jKHHeufS0#t=2m40s

Comment: @traal Just because some crappy solution was used at one time doesn't mean it's a preferable way to do it again, is it? I had all of this on the Apple II, so no need to do it again. Also, you're aware, that the video shows a C64, using an independant sound chip, much like the question was about?

Comment: @Raffzahn later editions of the Commodore PET use the 6522's shift register for generating audio; a well-circulated contemporaneous mod added the same to the original. No other modulation though, so more limited than your proposal.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure the Altair 8800 had sound output by adding a simple DAC and putting next to a radio.  However, this doesn't help the OP because it's not really a "sound chip".

Comment: @Raffzahn Could the same be done with a 555 chip in place of the 6522?

Comment: @traal For the AY-1-0212? Yes and no. With a 555 (without additional logic) you'll get only one base frequency, so only 8 sounds. Also, it woudl be additional logic. The idea of using the 6522 was not only about more controll, but also in saving components, as, without reprogramming, timer 1 will act much like a NE555. In either case, the advantage of using an independant source reduces the needd of CPU intervention to only when sounds/notes change . Note duration coudl be set with timer 2, so an interrupt could occure to mind the CPU for change. Not to mention the glitch free change on timers

Comment: @Raffzahn: A 1977 Atari 2600 can real-time synthesize four-voice music using 46 cycles (out of 76) per scan line.  That's gobbling a pretty hefty chunk of CPU, but the remaining 30 cycles/line are enough to show a pretty title screen (do a youtube search for "Stella's Stocking").  That cart wasn't designed in 1977 of course, but the only "special" hardware on it is for memory bank-switching (music would have taken up about 3/4 of a non-bank-switched cartridge).

Comment: @supercat I'm well aware what can be done - I did VCS programming (payed) back when it was new.

Comment: @Raffzahn: Really?  What'd you do on it?  I don't think any games "back-in-the-day" other than Pitfall II ever did real-time waveform generation; if I hadn't done my BTP2 music driver I doubt anyone would ever have known it was possible without extra hardware.

Comment: @Raffzahn: Incidentally, it's possible to build an 8K cart for the 2600 using a PROM and one other chip that would have been available off the shelf in the 1970s, but the designs I know of from back then generally required three chips plus the EPROM, which is likely a significant factor in why 4K games were more common than 8K [since a number of carts actually had 8K PROM chips that were half blank, the cost of the memory doesn't seem to have been a factor unless the vendors had gotten ROMs with bad bits at a discount].

Comment: @supercat Not sure what your PROMs got to do with the question asked. I did several promotional games.

Answer (score 2):

There was a game for the TRS-80 that used RF interference from the display as a sound source. You were instructed to place a radio next to the TV to hear sound.

Answer (score 1):

Although it wasn't done often, it was possible in that era to build a rather powerful sound generator by combining a CPU, a ROM, a DAC, and maybe some RAM.  The DAC need not be anything fancy--a bunch of resistors would suffice.  I don't think Eugene Jarvis' 6800-based sound board goes back quite that far, but a 6502 running at 1.19Mhz with 128 bytes of RAM and two four-bit DACs (hardware found in an Atari 2600 from 1977) can produce four-voice music (61-note full chromatic scale) at a sample rate of 15.75KHz using 46 cycles out of every 76 for sound generation.  A CDP1802 microprocessor might have been able to do likewise without needing any RAM if some creative addressing logic were wired in, but I don't know how the price of the 1802 would compare with that of a 6502 plus a RIOT (RAM+I/O+timer) chip.

Comment: The question was about off the shelf sound chips, right?

Comment: @Raffzahn: Even off-the-shelf "sound chips" often required adding  some  extra components.  If the goal is to get sound out of period-correct hardware, feeding a cheap (even in 1977) processor code that spends most of its time generating sound would have been a decent way to go about it.

Comment: Just that wasn't asked. The question is explicit about a dedicated sound chip. He didn't ask for ways to make sound, or did he? So shouldn't we respekt that and stay with the question asked?

Comment: @Raffzahn: The question did not restrict itself to single-chip solutions; what was excluded were 1980s chips.  The Atari 2600 wasn't a single-chip solution, but it was certainly available in 1977 as an off-the-shelf module, and all of the parts therein were available off the shelf except the video chip which could (if one didn't need video) be replaced with an 8-bit CMOS latch and 16 resistors.

Comment: And the TIA was available as part for everyone? Mind to cite *any* source?

Comment: @Raffzahn: If no video was needed, the TIA portion of the 2600 (which was used only as a DAC) could be replaced with a 6- or 8-bit CMOS latch and 16 resistors.  Such things would have been available in 1977.  If CMOS was hard to get, one could build a DAC using TTL and some discrete transistors.

Comment: Actually, one could probably get by with just the 6507, a RIOT, a ROM, some resistors, a couple transistors, and an oscillator (Stella's Stocking doesn't use the RIOT I/O pins for its DAC, but they could be used for that purpose in an audio board).  Three chips seems pretty reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

"Sound chip" is an ambiguous term that has changed over time.  There were audio DAC ICs available in the 1977 time frame.  But the non-captive audio ICs did not include any DMA (there were no usable common bus standards at that time) or any significant DSP capabilities.  But there were chips that produced a few "beeps" available near that time frame.

A capable "sound chip" at that time was more likely a large PCB for the S-100 bus or DEC minicomputer.  Circa 1979 or '80, there were also some fairly full featured sound cards for the Apple II.  But not chips.

Comment: Mockingboard I based on the GI AY-3-8910 was available in 1978 for the Apple II, and so was the ALF's Apple Music Synthesizer, also based on a single chip sound generator(can't remember which).